# How to manually replace ones RIL

Tags: cyanogenmod, radio-firmware

Is it possible to manually replace the RIL on a Samsung Galaxy S2?

I had previously flashed my device with CyanogenMod but lost my stock RIL due to careless use of the GetRIL app, so currently have no carrier network.

I have the details for the RIL (`md5sum 163ecafa01912637fe344ec1f8264d70` for baseband `I9100XXKE7`) but it is not in the GetRIL database so I can't get it back.

I was wondering if it is possible to get the RIL that comes with CyanogenMod and install that on my phone to avoid having to reflash it.

See my related question: [Samsung Galaxy S2 drops carrier network](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/61353/samsung-galaxy-s2-drops-carrier-network?noredirect=1#comment83441_61353)

Comment: Not really a solution but I ended up reflashing with CyanogenMod.  Bit of a pain but couldn't find another way :(

Answer (score 1):

This question depends on the firmware you've got installed.  If you've got CyanogenMod installed, then you should also have [ClockWorkMod (CWM)](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/ClockWorkMod_Instructions) installed, which is a utility for flashing your phone, among other things.

First you'll need to download the RIL to your phone as a zip file.  They should come packaged this way.  Save it to an sdcard, preferably in the root directory for easy access.

[This page](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/All_About_Recovery_Images) lists the different ways to access CWM depending on your phone model.  For the SGS2, turn the device off, then hold Vol+, Home and Power buttons until the screen flashes, then release them and wait for CWM to display.  From there, use the volume buttons to scroll and the power button to select, as touchscreen is disabled.

Select "install zip from sdcard", then navigate to the zip file and select it.  (Protip:  scroll up to skip the huge list of folders)  Wait for the installation to finish, then select "reboot system now" and you're done.  Enjoy your new RIL.